Water damage to wood subfloors
I live on 1st floor over carport of ‘70’s built wood frame apartment condo. Water leaked from a new kitchen fridge waterline causing water to pool under subfloors for 3 summer months before ceiling in carport burst open. Is it possible that the subfloors were warped by the pooling water? My insurance co replaced all my laminate floors but they are no longer level and there is sloping. The floors also now creak and squeak when walking on them. Should my subfloors have been repaired or replaced? Should the floors have been levelled again? The laminate was professionally installed with levelling 2-1/2 years before water damage and they were not sloped and didn’t creak and squeak.

It depends on too much more information.  Did the water soak the sub floor or go straight down to the ceiling?  What is the sub floor made of?  The new floor should not have been placed on bad/damaged sub floor.  Insurance should pay for replacement and doing it right, but you probably will move before then.

If the subfloor was wet for months, I'd be very surprised if it wasn't warped.
